# UV offset not offsetting correctly

Tags: unreal-engine4, texture-mapping

I was playing around with uv offset in unreal-engine 4. So Far I learned that the origin starts at the upper left hand corner and U scales from 0 to 1 from left to right and V from top to bottom. For a texture, if I add some constant value lets say 0.25 to U it should shift to right but it is shifting to left. same with adding or subtracting with V. Its like the axes are inverted or something. So Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are not shifting the texture, you are shifting the value of the UV coordinate of the pixel that's being shaded. So where previously you had U=0, now you have U=.25, and therefore where previously you were seeing the 0%th pixel of the texture, you are not seeing the 25%th pixel of the texture.

Comment: your answer is a little bit difficult to visualize but now I understand what's happening. Thanks a lot for answering the question